# Componente Boleto.Net Gerando Código Errado

Tags: dll, boleto, c#

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca boleto.net, estou gerando boletos do banco do brasil e está me ocorrendo o seguinte problema.

Estou gerando o boleto certinho mas o código de barras do boleto está vindo com o final, onde seria a área de FATOR DE VENCIMENTO + VALOR DO BOLETO errados.

Abaixo código retornado da propriedade BoletoBancario.Boleto.CodigoBarra.Codigo
00196.88472 32677.473001 00000.085183 1 **550000000002**

Abaixo código retornado da propriedade BoletoBancario.Boleto.CodigoBarra.LinhaDigitavelFormatada
00190.00009 02688.473269 77473.0000000085187 1 **67830000055000**

Se analisar os códigos acima, se tirarmos o trecho final(**550000000002**) do primeiro e inserirmos o final do segundo código(**67830000055000**) o boleto é gerado corretamente.

```
string convenio = "2677473";

var contaBancaria = new ContaBancaria()
                {
                    Agencia = "4175",
                    DigitoAgencia = "2",
                    Conta = "6141",
                    DigitoConta = "5",
                    OperacaConta = "019"
                };

var cedente = new Cedente()
                {
                    Codigo = convenio, //ced.ID.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0'),
                    //Convenio = Convert.ToInt32(convenio),
                    CPFCNPJ = ced.CPF_CNPJ,
                    Nome = ced.RAZAO_SOCIAL.ToUpper(),
                    ContaBancaria = contaBancaria                  
                };

var sacado = new Sacado()
                {
                    CPFCNPJ = "",
                    Nome = "",
                    Endereco = new Endereco()
                    {
                        End = "",
                        Bairro = "",
                        Cidade = "",
                        UF = "",
                        CEP = ""
                    }
                };

var boleto = new Boleto()
                {                
                    ContaBancaria = contaBancaria,
                    DataVencimento = "2016-05-03",
                    ValorBoleto = "550.00",
                    NossoNumero = "26774730000000085",
                    NumeroDocumento = "0000000085",
                    Carteira = "18",
                    Cedente = cedente,
                    Sacado = sacado,
                    EspecieDocumento = new EspecieDocumento_BancoBrasil("4"),                    
                    LocalPagamento = "QUALQUER BANCO",
                    Instrucoes = new List<IInstrucao>() { new Instrucao_BancoBrasil() { Descricao = "" } },
                };

var boleto_bancario = new BoletoBancario()
                {
                    CodigoBanco = 001,
                    Boleto = boleto,
                    MostrarCodigoCarteira = false,
                    MostrarComprovanteEntrega = false
                };

boleto_bancario.Boleto.Valida();

boleto_bancario.MontaHtmlEmbedded();
```

Esses são os dados que são preenchidos, teria algo de errado ou que está faltando?

Answer (score 1):

Eu tava olhando aqui o código fonte do código de barras...

https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/blob/master/src/Boleto.Net/Boleto/CodigoBarra.cs

Aparentemente o campo livre está mal informado.

Quando você pede a linha formatada, ele calcula assim sem o campo livre. Por isso funciona. Quando você pede apenas a propriedade `Codigo`, ele formata a string com o campo livre no final.

Sugestão: roda com o fonte mais atual do BoletoNet, pode ser um bug já resolvido. Se você tem certeza que seu código tá todo correto, monta um case mínimo e [abre uma issue](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/issues).

Comment: Obrigado Renan pela força! Olha, acredito que esteja certo sim mas vou abrir um issue para ver essa questão.

Comment: Bom dia Renan, 

Obrigado pela ajuda e pelos links que enviou! 

Acho que encontrei o problema, alterei os valores da carteira e nosso número e acabou gerando o código de barras corretamente!

00190.00009 02677.473269 88473.098189 1 67900000001000

Eu estava concatenando o nosso número + o código do convênio e isso estava gerando um número acima das 17 posições que é o correto. Em virtude disso, o código estava estourando e por isso que gerava errado o código de barras.

Obrigado pela ajuda!